# unable to make linq query : telerik open source

Tags: c#, entity-framework, telerik, telerik-open-access

I have 1 parent and 2 child tables each containing flag, i wanted to bring all those records from respective tables if there flag = "t". i have written so far:

```
ParentEntity obj = context.ParentEntity.Where(p => p.ID == 4).SingleOrDefault();
```

This brings me to 1 parent row and 4 rows from each child table.
out of those 4, only 1 flag="t" and rest flag ="f".

I do not want all rows. please guide me.

Comment: You could use a query like the following one to try to filter the objects based on their flag (I assume you have one-to-many setup between parent and child entities):
var result = context.GetAll<ChildEntity>()
                    .Where(c => c.Flag && c.Parent.Flag)
                    .GroupBy(c => c.Parent);

Comment: Now you could access the items in the following manner:

foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Key.Name); // item.Key is the parent
                    foreach (var child in item)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(child.Name);
                    }
                }

Comment: Hi Sir, thanks for your reply, it works fine if only one child, how will this query be modified in case of multiple childs i.e context.GetAll<ChildEntityOne>().GetAll<ChildEntityTwo>() ???

Comment: You could union both sequence in one result set using the Union operator - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386993(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: actually their is parent child relationship between these tables so union seems a strange option